# Best approach to get number of zeros in binary String

Tags: algorithm, binary

I'm having one binary string and have to calculate the number of zeros in that string

i know we can solve it with linear time but i want solution with o(k)

where k is number of zeros in string.

N be the length of String 1<=N<10^6

Comment: By o(k) you mean O(1) -- constant complexity or O(n) -- linear complexity?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8871279/7629882

Comment: k means number of zeros in  string

Comment: @arash the solution they given will applicable for numbers which can be represented in binary but in my case binary string length is larger so we can not represent it in decimal format

Comment: You can take 32/64 bits at a time and convert them into integers, and then follow that procedure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of 1's in binary representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871204/count-number-of-1s-in-binary-representation)

Answer (score 4):

Given a string of `N` independent bits, you will have to look at each bit at least once. This gives a time complexity of O(N). There is no way to do it asymptotically faster.

The algorithms given in the mentioned questions assume, that the whole bit string fits into a word and can be handled in O(1). This does not hold, if the string can be arbitrarily long.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) algorithm, *actually* calculate **hamming distance** of the string then `subtract` from the size of your binary string (N)