# Count 1's in binary representation in O(n) and O(log n) where n is number of bits

Tags: java, algorithm, binary, time-complexity

I have two task - count 1's in binary representation in O(n) and O(log n). As the first part is easy, I can't figure out how can I count them in O(log n) as it's not sorted or anything. Is that even possible?
My code so far:

```
public class CountOnes {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("Program to count ones");
    countOnesInLinearTime("110");
    countOnesInlogarithmicTime("110");
  }

  private static void countOnesInlogarithmicTime(String binaryRepresentationOfLong) {
    //TODO
  }

  private static void countOnesInLinearTime(String binaryRepresentationOfLong) {
    int numberOfOnes = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < binaryRepresentationOfLong.length(); i++)
    {
      if(binaryRepresentationOfLong.charAt(i) == '1')
      {
        numberOfOnes++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(numberOfOnes);
  }
}
```

I have found: [Count number of 1's in binary representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871204/count-number-of-1s-in-binary-representation) but it's slightly different.

Comment: I assume that you need to do this for an `int`, `long`, etc., well something that supports *shifting*?

Comment: are you sure about your solution? `String` is not binary representation of anything

Comment: Is the input always a string? If so, then you'd have to look at every character. According to this comment on the question you linked, the solution there would be logN given an integer input https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871204/count-number-of-1s-in-binary-representation#comment11645629_8871435

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your input string will be integer, not in string, it's achievable using Brian Kernighan’s Algorithm:

Subtraction of 1 from a number toggles all the bits (from right to left) till the rightmost set bit(including the rightmost set bit). So if we subtract a number by 1 and do bitwise & with itself (`n & (n-1)`), we unset the rightmost set bit. If we do `n` & `(n-1)` in a loop and count the no of times loop executes we get the set bit count.

The beauty of this solution is the number of times it loops is equal to the number of set bits in a given integer.

```
1. Initialize count: = 0
2. If integer n is not zero
      (a) Do bitwise & with (n-1) and assign the value back to n
          n: = n&(n-1)
      (b) Increment count by 1
      (c) go to step 2
3. Else return count
```

**Implementation**

```
int countNumberOfOnes(int n) { 
    int count = 0; 
    while (n > 0) { 
        n &= (n - 1); 
        count++; 
    } 
    return count; 
}
```

Comment: How is this logarithmic in the number of bits?

Comment: it's not logarithmic in "number of bits". A number `n` requires atmost `O(logn)` numbers of bits to represent it in binary. So the complexity is `O(logn)` where `n` is the number

Comment: See the title " ... where n is number of bits".

Comment: I see. I think OP is overestimating the constraint.

Comment: I am not the author of that task. I accepted this answer because: `The beauty of this solution is the number of times it loops is equal to the number of set bits in a given integer.`As we are not magicans we can't predict the future.

Answer (score 4):

You can count the number of set bits in a `long` as follows:

```
long l = 1425142514251425142L; // some value
long c = l;
c = ((c >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555L) + (c & 0x5555555555555555L);
c = ((c >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333L) + (c & 0x3333333333333333L);
c = ((c >> 4) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL) + (c & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL);
c = ((c >> 8) & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffL) + (c & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffL);
c = ((c >> 16) & 0x0000ffff0000ffffL) + (c & 0x0000ffff0000ffffL);
c = ((c >> 32) & 0x00000000ffffffffL) + (c & 0x00000000ffffffffL);
```

We basically perform *O(n)* times, with *n* the number of bits, a similar operation. For the `i`'th step (with `i` starting from `1`), we perform an operation like:

```
c = ((c >> 2i) & mask) + (c & mask);
```

The mask has as binary structure:

```
0101010101010101
0011001100110011
0000111100001111
0000000011111111
...
```

So for the `i`-th step it is a repitition of `2i` zeros, followed by `2i` ones, and this is repeated until we reach the 64 bits.

How does this work? By shifting a `2i` places to the right, we "align" two parts of the number. The first part is the ones that are placed where the `mask` has zeros, and the other part where the mask has ones. We then sum up the two.

In the first step this means that for every two bits, we align the bits to the right, sum these up, and the result of this sum (a value between `0` and `2`, both inclusive), can be represented on two bits. So now `c` contains a sequence of 32 2-bit numbers that each represent the sum of the number of two bits.

In the next iteration, we again perform an alignment, and now we sum up 16 of those 2-bit numbers with their neighbor on the left (so the other 16 2-bit numbers), which can result in values from `0` to `4`, so we can represent that number of 3 bits, but we use space for 4 bits.

Each iteration we thus sum up `2i-1` numbers with other `2i`, and after *O(log n)*, we finally sum up two *n/2* bit numbers, which yield the total number of set bits.

We here make the assumption that we can add two numbers together in constant time, as well as shifting and masking in constant time. If the numbers are arbitrary large, that is not the case, hence the algorithm is, strictly speaking not *O(log n)*, in fact for arbitary large numbers, this algorithm is even worse.

That being said, you can not count arbitrary long algorithms faster than *Ω(n)*, since it requires at least to read over each bit once to determine its value, unless of course you know something about the structure of the number in advance that you could exploit.

Comment: @Henry: that is exactly what the last paragraph is about. One can sum up two arbitrary large integers in *O(n)*, and one can also do the masking and shifting simultenously (without costing more), but as said, this is indeed not *O(n log)* given that we take the time complexity of the arithmetic into account.

Comment: This is one of the optimization but the growth rate is not `O(logn)`.

Comment: @Kaidul: as said before in case the bit size is fixed (the size is *n*), it will require *n* such steps, and we here make the assumption that addition, masking and shifting are done in constant time, but for arbitrary large numbers, that is not possible. It is simply impossible to count the bits of an arbitrary large number in less than *&Omega;(n)*.

Comment: @Kaidul: What I mean with *log n* steps is that for a 32-bit `int`, it would take one step less. For a (hypothetical) 128-bit number, it will take one step more, etc. for a 256-bit number, it would take one step extra. But the steps are, like all shifting/bitwise operations and additions, do not run in constant time, these run linear with the number of bits if we implement these in software, or *O(log n)* in some cases in hardware (since we can use "hardware parallelism").