# Filter elements in the list A, based on the list B, such that for a in A there exists at least one element b in B, where a = (a&b)

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

I have 2 lists of ints: A and B. How can I efficiently ensure that for every element in A there exists at least one element in B such that when they are bit-anded, answer is that element in A.

Eg. B = [14,  13 ]

So for elements in A:
a1 = 12 is valid as 12&14 = 12
a2 = 3 is not valid as 3&14 = 2 and 3&13 = 1

A and B can have 10^10 entries.

I am reading B as a column from csv and generating A on fly. And checking for above condition using

df.applymap(lambda x: (x&a) == a ).any().any()

But as size of B increases this check is my bottleneck.

Comment: What are the limits for the numbers?

Comment: A [MRE] that's starts by defining sample lists A and B would be good.

Comment: If you're generating `A` on the fly, you can simply pick a random `b` in `B` then flip any random zero-bits in `b`, and insert that into `A`. However, if you already have `A` and want to verify that each `a` in it has at least one matching `b` that meets your criteria, there may not be a much better algorithm than brute force, though heuristics/pruning may improve performance a little bit.

Comment: a = a & b means b has at least all the bits set that a has. So maybe you can use a prefix tree to check for b efficiently.

Comment: What does generating A "on fly" mean? You said you already had a list A.

Comment: @qwr: Perhaps A is a deterministic list, generated according to some rule (e.g. "all primes up to ten billion"), but generated on-the-fly as opposed to being precomputed and stored? Hopefully the OP will clarify.

Comment: Sorry new to asking a question. Not sure how to see all the comments and respond to them. Yes A is deterministic and can have any combination generated from C[n,r-m].

Comment: What are C, n, r and m, and what does "C[n,r-m]" mean?

Comment: @nocomment C[n,r-m] represents combination or r-m elements chosen from n elements. r-m<n and I am choosing arbitrary m to show that for some element, bitwise and will satisfy my above constraint. Currently I am dealing with n=64 but this can increase with time. m typically in my case is 2.

Comment: And what is r ?

Comment: r can vary from 64 to 2

Comment: And why do you use r-m? What is the meaning of that? Why not just say C[n,r] and r varies from 62 to 0?

Comment: That is to differentiate between the 2 lists A and B. B:=C[n,r] and A:=C[n,r-m]. This makes sure that a&b=a is possible.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Don't you think all this is important information that absolutely should be in the question?

Comment: How does this change my question? It is more generic and captures what I want to do. Why it is feasible doesn't impact that answer.

Comment: Two things. First, it might allow us to generate realistic data for testing. Second, and more importantly, you're asking for efficiency. If you ask "How can I efficiently sort a list of numbers", the proper answer is "Call its sort method". But if your list only contains zeros and ones, then there's a far more efficient way. Such details can entirely change the task and what's efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If speed is a concert you can try to use [numba](/questions/tagged/numba):

```py
from numba import njit


@njit
def check(a, b):
    for val_a in a:
        for val_b in b:
            if (val_b & val_a) == val_a:
                return True
    return False


a = np.array([12, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.array([14, 13], dtype=np.uint8)

print(check(a, b))
```

Prints:

```
True
```

---

Benchmark:

```py
from statistics import median
from timeit import repeat

np.random.seed(42)


def setup():
    a = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=10_000_000, dtype=np.uint8)
    b = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=10_000_000, dtype=np.uint8)
    return a, b


t = repeat(
    "check(a, b)", setup="a, b = setup()", repeat=1000, number=1, globals=globals()
)

print(f"t={median(t):.8f}")
```

On my computer (AMD 5700x) this prints:

```
t=0.00000496
```

---

EDIT: For `np.uint64` values from `0` to `MAX(np.unit64)`:

```
def setup():
    a = np.random.randint(0, np.iinfo(np.uint64).max, size=10_000_000, dtype=np.uint64)
    b = np.random.randint(0, np.iinfo(np.uint64).max, size=10_000_000, dtype=np.uint64)
    return a, b


t = repeat(
    "check(a, b)", setup="a, b = setup()", repeat=50, number=1, globals=globals()
)

print(f"t={median(t):.8f}")
```

Prints:

```
t=0.04230742
```

---

EDIT 2: Sorting the first 1000 items from `B` array according bit-count:

```py
from statistics import median
from timeit import repeat

np.random.seed(42)


# https://stackoverflow.com/a/68943135/10035985
@njit
def bit_count(arr):
    # Make the values type-agnostic (as long as it's integers)
    t = arr.dtype.type
    mask = t(-1)
    s55 = t(0x5555555555555555 & mask)  # Add more digits for 128bit support
    s33 = t(0x3333333333333333 & mask)
    s0F = t(0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F & mask)
    s01 = t(0x0101010101010101 & mask)

    arr = arr - ((arr >> np.uint8(1)) & s55)
    arr = (arr & s33) + ((arr >> np.uint8(2)) & s33)
    arr = (arr + (arr >> np.uint8(4))) & s0F
    return (arr * s01) >> np.uint16((8 * (arr.itemsize - 1)))


@njit
def check(a, b):
    b[:1000] = b[np.argsort(bit_count(b[:1000]))[::-1]]

    for val_a in a:
        for val_b in b:
            if (val_b & val_a) == val_a:
                return True
    return False


def setup():
    a = np.random.randint(0, np.iinfo(np.uint64).max, size=10_000_000, dtype=np.uint64)
    b = np.random.randint(0, np.iinfo(np.uint64).max, size=10_000_000, dtype=np.uint64)
    return a, b


check(np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.uint64), np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.uint64))

t = repeat(
    "check(a, b)", setup="a, b = setup()", repeat=50, number=1, globals=globals()
)

print(f"t={median(t):.8f}")
```

Prints:

```
t=0.04198640
```

---

EDIT3: If you want to check every element from A to array B:

```py
@njit
def check(a, b):
    for val_a in a:
        for val_b in b:
            if (val_b & val_a) == val_a:
                break
        else:
            return False
    return True


def setup():
    a = np.random.randint(0, np.iinfo(np.uint64).max, size=10_000_000, dtype=np.uint64)
    b = np.random.randint(0, np.iinfo(np.uint64).max, size=10_000_000, dtype=np.uint64)
    return a, b


check(np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.uint64), np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.uint64))

t = repeat(
    "check(a, b)", setup="a, b = setup()", repeat=50, number=1, globals=globals()
)

print(f"t={median(t):.8f}")
```

Prints:

```
t=0.00415215
```

---

EDIT4: Parralel version that creates mask:

```py
from statistics import median
from timeit import repeat

import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def check(a, b):
    out = np.ones_like(a, dtype=np.uint8)

    for i in prange(len(a)):
        val_a = a[i]

        for val_b in b:
            if (val_b & val_a) == val_a:
                break
        else:
            out[i] = 0

    return out


def setup():
    a = np.random.randint(0, np.iinfo(np.uint64).max, size=1_000_000, dtype=np.uint64)
    b = np.random.randint(0, np.iinfo(np.uint64).max, size=1_000_000, dtype=np.uint64)
    return a, b


check(np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.uint64), np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.uint64))

t = repeat("check(a, b)", setup="a, b = setup()", repeat=1, number=1, globals=globals())

print(f"t={median(t):.8f}")
```

Prints:

```
t=79.79640480
```

Comment: With 8 bits, I doubt they would've asked. How long does this take with 16, 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: @nocomment I've tried int with int64 and randint from 1 to 1_000_000 and the speed is comparable. The key is to break at first find, not do comparison on whole array as numpy does.

Comment: How about real 64 bit values, not limited to 1_000_000?

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm just still waiting for their answer.

Comment: I guess you could optimize it further by sorting B from high to low bitcounts, or even removing B-values that are a subbitset of another B-value.

Comment: @nocomment I think depends on the data OP have, just doing plain `np.sort(a)` yields time in `t=0.7` range. For random data I think the best strategy is just brute force it.

Comment: Why would you sort A? And why by value?

Comment: Oh I guess you mean just to see *any* time for sorting? How about sorting just the first 1000 B values from high to low bitcounts? That should be faster than 0.04230742 and might reduce that by more than what it costs.

Comment: @nocomment See my EDIT2, I hope I've implemented the bit counting right (borrowed it from other answer). But even increasing the sorting to first 10_000 it yields the same result.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem. Your `check` is wrong, isn't it? Shouldn't `return` from the inner loop. You're not doing all the work.

Comment: @nocomment I think it's ok - *... for every element in A there exists at least one element in B such that when they are bit-anded...* - that means if we find at least one element B, return `True`.

Comment: No. As you quoted, it says *"for **every** element in A"*. Not *"for at least one element in A"*.

Comment: @nocomment See my EDIT3 then, I've added this alternative. The result is then even faster.

Comment: Better but still wrong. They said they want to **filter** A to **ensure** that every A-element has a match. You instead check whether that happens to already be the case. That's very different.

Comment: @nocomment That I leave on OP what **exactly** he wants. The basic framework is laid here already.

Comment: But with completely misleading runtimes.

Comment: List A can have valid as well as invalid elements. I want to identify those invalid  elements and filter them out.

Comment: @Nihar Then this solution won't scale to 10 millions x 10 millions of values. I've posted parallel version that creates mask (you can use the mask afterwards to filter the `A` array), but for one million values in A and one million values in B (it takes ~80 seconds).

Comment: @AndrejKesely let me evaluate your solution. Will try it out tomorrow.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I tried your solution and for some cases it ran for more than 5-6 hrs on 9 cores. Size of my problem is about ~500 millions x 500 millions and expected to go up.